# How to display a heatmap on a specific parameter with geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas, geoplot

In my very simple case I would like to display the heatmap of the points in the `points` GeoJSON file but **not** on the geographic density (lat, long). In the `points` file each point has a `confidence` property (a value from 0 to 1), how to display the heatmap on this parameter? `weight=points.confidence` don't seem to work.

for exemple:

```py
#points.geojson
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.67}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.703471404215918, 26.541625492300192 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.76}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.009744331225093, 26.710090585532761 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.94}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.541708538306224, 26.160111944646022 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.52}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.628566642215354, 25.917300595223857 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.46}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.676499267124271, 26.653959791866598 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.55}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.677033863264533, 26.654033815175087 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.12}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.37522057234797, 26.353271000367258 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.62}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.396556958266373, 26.459196264023291 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.21}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 36.879775221618168, 26.901743663072878 ] } }
]
}
```

The image below shows my result but it is on the geographic density not confidence score density.

```py
import geoplot as gplt
import geopandas as gpd
import geoplot.crs as gcrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = gpd.read_file('points.geojson')
polygons = gpd.read_file('polygons.geojson')

ax = gplt.polyplot(polygons, projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea(), zorder=1)
gplt.kdeplot(points, cmap='Reds', shade=True, clip=polygons, ax=ax) 
#weight=points.confidence don’t work inside kdeplot()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do.  in **plotly** I would do a density plot of *confidence* and add a layer to show geometric boundaries.  if you provided your data as links (polygons & confidence by lat/lon) I can code up to demonstrate

Comment: @RobRaymond Thanks a lot, I edited to add some exemple of data (no real) in .geojson format, is it enought for a demonstration ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1tUBOC6HHBVwjKsaD1lzqqV89izq1A0J-/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103278989014641927536&rtpof=true&sd=true  Do you want to do something like that? I did it long ago. I used folium that time.

Comment: @VisheshMangla yes for example it would be nice, is it possible to display the heat map on another parameter? the confidence in my case.

Comment: yes , it is. When I tried it at time I had used some parameter to give the colours and  the points. I used folium for the maps. https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Getting-Started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- using your sample data for points
- these points are in Saudi Arabia, so assumed that polygons are regional boundaries in Saudi Arabia.  Downloaded this from http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/
- polygon data is a **shape** file

  1. loaded into **geopandas** to allow interface to *GEOJSON* `__geo__interface`
  2. dynamically filtered this to Saudi using **pandas** `.loc`
- confidence data is just a straight https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-density-heatmaps/
- boundaries are https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/

```
# fmt: off
points = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.67}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.703471404215918, 26.541625492300192 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.76}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.009744331225093, 26.710090585532761 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.94}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.541708538306224, 26.160111944646022 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.52}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.628566642215354, 25.917300595223857 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.46}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.676499267124271, 26.653959791866598 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.55}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.677033863264533, 26.654033815175087 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.12}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.37522057234797, 26.353271000367258 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.62}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 37.396556958266373, 26.459196264023291 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"confidence": 0.21}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 36.879775221618168, 26.901743663072878 ] } }
]
}
# fmt: on
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib

# fmt: off
# download boundaries
url = "https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])
# fmt: on

if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(f.stem)

# load downloaded boundaries
gdf2 = gpd.read_file(str(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).joinpath(f"{f.stem}.shp")))

# confidence data
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(points)

# now the simple bit, densitity plot data and Saudi Arabia regional boundaries as a layer
fig = px.density_mapbox(
    gdf, lat=gdf.geometry.y, lon=gdf.geometry.x, z="confidence"
).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "zoom": 6,
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": gdf2.loc[gdf2["iso_a2"].eq("SA")].geometry.__geo_interface__,
                "type": "line",
            }
        ],
    },
    margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"b":0}
)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to create an interpolation somehow that you would have *confidence* values not only defined by the Point (coordinates) but with the heatmap kind of smoothing out the colors but respecting the boundaries of the .shl file?